# Injecting secrets in Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, passwords, multibranch-pipeline

I have local jenkins setup with admin access.

I have configured plugins as per this https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs.

Though, I am still unclear about how to inject secrets in Jenkins multibranch pipeline jobs. I could not see any configurations option to either set the environemntal variables as well. PS - I do not want to commit secrets in git ;)

Need to inject them as secrets from Jenkins.

Answer (score 4):

I used credentials plugin to store credentials and credentials binding plugin to map them to environmental variables. Here is how I did it:

```groovy
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID', variable: 'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID')]) {
}
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID', variable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID')]) {
}
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_TENANT_ID', variable: 'AZURE_TENANT_ID')]) {
}
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET', variable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET')]) {
}
```

Comment: And where would those `withCredentials` calls all go? In the Jenkinsfile? Any particular place?

Comment: No.. You need to use Jenkings credentials plugin and inject secrets in to the variables. And then you can define the above statements in Jenkinsfile. with this, now the variables are available as environment vairables in jenkins workspace.