# How to insert properties in Jenkinsfile in multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I configured jenkins multibranch pipeline on Jenkins version 2.60.2
I'm looking for a way to keep my passwords in jenkins multibranch pipline configuration, so Jenkinsfile could take them as parameters for execution of its stages. Is there a way to set these properties within the jenkins UI?
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007850/injecting-secrets-in-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline), but I think there is a more preferred way.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. What are you actually trying to accomplish?  It sounds like you want to inject secrets into your `Jenkinsfile`, and the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) and [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) is the de facto way to accomplish that. There is also [CloudBees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204897020-Fetch-a-userid-and-password-from-a-Credential-object-in-a-Pipeline-job-) documentation on that approach.

Comment: Could you mention these plugins in an answer to my question. I will accept it. My question was about what plugins to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using credentials in a Jenkins Pipeline, there are a couple plugins that I would consider essentially part of the Jenkins Core (even though they are plugins):

- [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)
- [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin)

These can combine to give you a way to administratively manage credentials as well as provide for ways to consume them inside of Jobs. There are additional plugins built on top of these providing credential type implementations. For example, the [SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) allows you to store SSH credentials in Jenkins.

The Credentials Binding Plugin provides the `withCredentials` step. The [documentation has some examples on how you could use it](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables). Here is an example from the documentation:

```groovy
node {
  withCredentials(
      [
          usernameColonPassword(
              credentialsId: 'mylogin', 
              variable: 'USERPASS'
          )
      ]
  ) {
    sh '''
          set +x
          curl -u $USERPASS https://private.server/ > output
        '''
  }
}
```